# MySQL JOIN with substring as a counter

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as follows:

**Table `xyz`**

```
id    url
--    -------------
1     someweb.com/1
2     example.com
3     abc.com
```

**Table `abc`**

```
id    url
--    -----------
1     example.com
```

And I am expecting output as:

```
id    url            count
--    -----------    -----
1     example.com    2
2     abc            1
```

And I execute this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    xyz.url,
    COUNT(xyz.url) as count
from      abc
LEFT JOIN xyz
on        abc.id = substring_index(xyz.url, '/someweb.com/', -1)
```

as some links are sitting in `abc` table which is linked as a string of `xyz`.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: i am seeing both table are same

Comment: Sorry, i updated 2nd table

Comment: why not this in out put  someweb.com/1    1

Comment: The expected results are not in line with your sample data or I just do not get what you want. Also, you are trying to join the id field on the url. The two are completely different.

Comment: what about other 2 rows in `xyz` table?

Comment: these are other url

Comment: @Shadow. yes because id of abc field is a string of xyz

Comment: Well, that's not what your sample data shows...

Comment: @Shadow See id under abc table is 1 and i have 1 in url of xyz..

Comment: @AnkitaKashyap can you give us more explanation

Comment: @Ankita Kashyap can u please try my answer and tell me if it helped

Comment: @AnkitaKashyap that only true for 1 record: `someweb.com/1`. For the rest, the join expression will not return any matches. Therefore I have no idea how `example.com` would get a count of 2.

Comment: @Shadow: i am fetching 1 from someweb.com/1 and  from abc against id=1, i have example.com

Comment: @Shadow: this is the requrement. i am setting up simple table only

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS count,
    u.url
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            xyz
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                abc
    ) AS u
GROUP BY
    u.url
```

Comment: This would return `someweb.com/1` with a count of 1, which is not in the expected results list.

Comment: @Shadow bro please check my answer now

Comment: I'm sorry, but you just made it even worse.

Comment: @Shadow no problem bro, I am just learning, so please tell me what is the problem.

Comment: You cannot simply manually exclude an inconvenient record from the resultset, when the requirements do not tell you to exclude it. At the moment the question is not clear as to how the expected results should be achieved. If you provide an answer despite the question being unclear, then you need to describe the assumptions you made, not just dump a piece of code.

Comment: @vSugumar: your first answer was giving me that result which i was expecting

Comment: @AnkitaKashyap that's funny because that query will not return the results you provided in the question.

Comment: @Ankita Kashyap bro I have updated my answer and if it helped you, you need to accept it as answer and upvote it. and that will make me happy bro.